# Set Console Windows Size and Remove Scrollbars

Tags: c++, console, resize, scrollbar, windows-console

I'm trying to set the size of the console windows with SetWindowPos(...), but I'd like to remove the scrollbars. I read that, in order to do that, I need to make the console screen buffer the same size as the console window, but I want the window smaller than the buffer The only way I found to have a window smaller than the buffer and removing the scrollbars is via "system(mode x, y)", but I'd prefer a more comfortable and better way. What can I do?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the window is smaller than the buffer, and there are no scrollbars, what good is the buffer area beyond of the window size, since you can never access it?

Comment: I use WriteConsoleOutput to emulate a camera, so I need also the area of buffer that can't be seen

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use actual console windows and not something more flexible? I guess it also won't work properly if an alternative console manager is installed that automatically attaches to your consoles, like ConEmu; and the user can also just resize the windows or change their buffer size in the properties, so you can't rely on these things.

Comment: I want to use the console, else I would have used some graphic library.